# Can't run istio on windows

Tags: istio

I am trying to run Istio on windows 10 machine. I have Kubernetes installed on minikube.

I am getting following error while I run any command for Istio for example : kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/istio-demo.yaml

error: SchemaError(io.k8s.api.authorization.v1beta1.ResourceRule): invalid object doesn't have additional properties

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered suggests that you might be missing Custom Resource Defintions. Have you applied this step #2 - Install all the Istio Custom Resource Definitions from [Installation guide](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/install/kubernetes/#installation-steps) ?

Additionally post installation of Istio, have you verified if all Istio components are up and running with (`kubectl get pods -n istio-system`) ?

I assumed you used the installation option: without helm

---

@Deepack please take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567312/minikube-kubernete-ingress-create-always-throws-errors), your issue looks similar, which means you might be having a kubctl & k8s-cluster versions mismatch